# Are these two mysql select queries identical functionality wise?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables. Table 1 and 2 share column 1 and 2. All 3 tables share column 2 (an ID column), but only table 3 contains column 3. I want all rows where tables 1,2 have equal values for columns 1 and 2, but only where table3.Col3 (joined on the ID column 2) is equal to some specific value "X".

I have two queries which *appear* to be identical and are working for what I want, but I am asking the experts to make sure they are interchangeable :

```
SELECT *
from Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1 and Table1.Col2 = Table2.Col2
WHERE (Select Col3 from Table3 where Table2.Col2 = Table3.Col2) = "X"

SELECT *  
from Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1 and Table1.Col2 = Table2.Col2 
INNER JOIN Table3 
ON Table1.Col2 = Table3.Col2
WHERE Table3.Col3 = "X"
```

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing the number of rows involved and description of the table.

Comment: Compare the execution times..?

Comment: Are they identical in terms of functionality? Edited my question to remove question of timing.

Comment: You're the only one who can test the speeds, because it will be specific to your database server.  Use the second version of your query and avoid using a nested select.

Comment: I was asking because I was unsure whether the two queries were even identical. All of you seem to be implicitly answering "yes".

Comment: `EXPLAIN` can be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to say yes they are equivalent, and try offering an explanation.

1st query:

The 1st `INNER JOIN` will only select rows from Table1 and Table2 where both `Col1` and `Col2` match. The subquery is in-fact a correlated subquery, which will be executed for each row of the outer subquery, which means every row filtered by the `INNER JOIN`. Additionally, you are filtering the outer query on the results of the inner query where `Col3` from `Table3 = 'X'`. This is giving you exactly the data you want.

2nd query:

Slightly different. 1st `INNER JOIN` works the same way as in case 1. However, then you `INNER JOIN` this result set with Table3. Again, you are only joining on rows where `Table1.Col2 = Table3.Col2`. And, since `Table1.Col2 = Table2.Col2`, it results in an equivalent intermediate result set as defined by the correlated subquery in the 1st case. Finally, you are filtering on `Table3.Col3 = 'X'`, which again results in the exact dataset as you wanted.

Hope this makes sense. Do correct me if my logic is wrong.

Comment: Please note that "SELECT *" will return different set of columns for these queries. And a subquery "Select Col3 from Table3 where Table2.Col2 = Table3.Col2" in the first query assumes that it will return no more than 1 row.

Comment: @miazo Great point. I completely ignored the first part of the queries.